# PHP Fat Free Framework: fails when GET params contain a URL

Tags: php, frameworks, fat-free-framework

I'm using Fat Free Framework and I want to handle an incoming request like:
http://example.com/api/method/?user_id=1&url=http://newsite.com

I use the `F3::route` method to handle GET requests to this method but I get the following error:

```
parse_url(/method?user_id=1&url=http://newsite.com): Unable to parse URL
```

I think I've tracked this down to a problem with the PHP function `parse_url()` which [fails on relative URLs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

Any ideas how I can get F3 to properly handle URLs in the GET query params?

Comment: The url should be url-encoded, meaning the `http://` should be `http:%2F%2F`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've run into this problem before.  If you don't have control of the incoming URL not being url-encoded, you can do this as a dirty hack before F3 is run to get rid of the slashes in the argument:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = str_replace('http://', 'http:', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Comment: it's a dirty hack ... but I'll take it!

Answer (score 0):

why not simplify and use `urlencode('http://www.google.com');`???